# Passing an additional argument in call to a function

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Imagine a scenario like so:

```
var obj = {
    renderSubGame: renderComponent
}
```

and renderSubGame is called with an argument this.subGameInfo like so:

```
renderSubGame(this.subGameInfo)
```

thus that argument would be passed on to renderComponent (which itself is indeed one thing I want)

but renderComponent also requires an argument for its parameter "component", which in this case I want its passed argument to be "subGame":

```
var obj = {
    renderSubGame: renderComponent('subGame')
}
```

but then I lose the parameter passed to renderSubGame.

**So how can I get both 'subGame' (via obj) and this.subGameInfo (via function call) as arguments to renderComponent?**

---

More specifically, this is the general scenario in my code:

**file/requirejs module: subGame.js**

with code such that subGame.render() calls an enclosed function renderSubGame() which ultimately calls view.renderSubGame(this.subGameInfo).

**file/requirejs module: view.js**

This is what the module returns for view:

```
return: {
    renderSubGame: renderComponent('subGame')
}
```

and this is what I want renderComponent to roughly be:

```
function renderComponent(component) {
    var renderMethods = _(render).getObjectMethodNames();                
        if (_(renderMethods).contains(component)) {
            render[component](*INITIAL_ARGS_FROM_SUBGAME.JS*);
    } else {
        throw 'Error: component method render.' + component + '() not 
        recognized as a method of render.';
    }
}
```

(render is another module that returns an object of methods, one of which is subGame)

---

So my issue is that the argument (this.subGameInfo) does not reach renderComponent.

I've tried solutions with .apply() or .call() but they haven't seem to worked the way I want.

If I were to use renderSubGame: renderComponent that would include the arguments from renderSubGame, so how can I add 'subGame' to those arguments?

Or alternatively, how can I get:

```
renderSubGame: renderComponent('subGame')
```

to include the arguments of

```
renderSubGame (this.subGameInfo)
```

in addition to 'subGame'?

Comment: Why don't you do `var obj = {renderSubGame: renderComponent, component: 'subGame'}` and then use both in `subGame.render()`?

Comment: Because eventually I plan to use other components. For example, I'd maybe want to renderComponent('line'), which, following your suggestion, would require: `var obj = { renderSubGame: renderComponent, renderLine: renderComponent, component: 'subGame', component: 'line' }` which obviously isn't valid

Comment: `var obj = {renderSubGame: renderComponent, renderSubGameArguments: ['subGame'], renderLine: renderComponent, renderLineArguments: ['line']}` or even better (in my opinion) `var obj = {renderSubGame: {target: renderComponent, args: ['subGame']}, renderLine: {target: renderComponent, args: ['line']}}`

Comment: @BrettBeatty I'd still need a way to for renderSubGame or renderLine to inform renderComponent which component to render. Correct me if I'm wrong tho. Maybe there's a way to get around that. I'd have to retrieve the caller function I suppose (I don't know if that's possible or advisable)

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're trying to do, you could just have whatever function needs to use it (`subGame.render`, maybe) read both what function to use and what arguments to give it.

Comment: @BrettBeatty I can give that a shot. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consider the code you tried:

```
var obj = {
    renderSubGame: renderComponent('subGame')
}
```

What you are doing there is setting the `obj.renderSubGame` to the value *returned from calling `renderComponent('subGame')`*. When you do `obj.renderSubGame()` later, it won't be calling `renderComponent` again. It will be calling the return value of the call that was made when `obj` was initialized.

You could get the effect you want by doing:

```
var obj = {
    renderSubGame: renderComponent.bind(undefined, 'subGame')
}
```

[bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) creates a new function with the initial arguments already bound to some values. The first argument to `bind` sets `this` inside the function. I've set it to `undefined` since you do not use `this` in `renderComponent`. Then the 2nd argument makes it so that when `obj.renderSubGame('foo', 1)` is called, it will be equivalent to calling `renderComponent('subGame', 'foo', 1)`.